# Android Studio can't install because it can't find jdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-8

Help...I just built my new computer and am trying to install android studio on it. I already have IntelliJ and JDK installed. So that is what I don't understand, I can't install Android Studio; I have it installed on my other computer (it is a macbook pro running Mac OSX El Capitan). My new computer is running Windows 10 Home 64 Bit.

When I run the installer .exe (I have also tried running it as administrator), I get this error:

[image: this]

Could it have anything to do with me moving my Users folder to my D: Drive? I used sysprep to move the users folder so my docs and stuff are on my mass storage drive.

Comment: show the contents of that directory `C:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_72` had better have a bin\java.exe. check the size of that file, too

Comment: it does and it is 203 KB

Answer (score 0):

It might be white space on your java folder location
Try to copy your jdk to another place with no white space

Comment: space between **Program** and **Files**, try use some place lik **C:\jdk1.8.0_72**

Comment: @seth-zerishnek-gower, if it is asking for jdk folder, installer not looking for JAVA_HOME for this