# intellij feature (...) not supported at this language level. I can't compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, foreach, java-8, java-7

IntelliJ is showing me [this error](http://prntscr.com/9vrazk)

I just built my new computer and none of my java stuff is working... My regular Intellij was working when I first tried it, but my android studio would't install because it couldn't find the path to the jdk. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007557/android-studio-cant-install-because-it-cant-find-jdk) is the question that I asked about that. Since that wasn't working, I had to reinstall java multiple times, and now my IntelliJ isn't working. Here is a picture of the error (I am getting an error that is telling me the for-each loops aren't supported at this language level).

I have tried to install the JDK on my D: drive and that didn't work. I am currently trying to use java 1.8u71 (have tried u65 and 1.7u47) except none of those have worked.

Comment: What are the compiler settings for the Project?

Comment: press alt+enter and click on the first fix suggested by intellij!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> IntelliJ is showing me this error

[image: are not supported at this language level]

### Matching the SDK/JDK with Project language level

To activate Java language features in the editor, you need to change your module's **Project Structure** or **Module Settings** to ensure your **Project SDK** matches the **Project language level**.

Project SDK (JDK) Java 1.5 matches project language level 5 ...

Java 1.6 matches language level 6 ...

Java 1.7 matches language level 7, and so on.

#### Example

Depending on your IntelliJ version, hit <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift - S</kbd> on your module in the Project pane, or hit <kbd>Ctrl + Shift - A</kbd> and type either "Project Structure" or "Module Settings" to open the Project Structure dialog.

Under **Project Settings** section, click on the first item in the list, **Project**.

In the screenshot below, the Project SDK `1.8 (java version '1.8.0_72')` matches the selected language level `SDK Default (8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.)` because Java 1.8 matches SDK level 8. **This activates the Java 8 language features for use in the editor.**

[image: project structure]

If you don't have the JDK set up under `Project SDK` that is a different problem. Solve that one first by clicking `New` and adding a JDK.

Comment: I had to go to "project structure" -> Modules -> "Sources" tab and change "Language Level" in the "Sources" tab.

Answer (score 26):

When I had multiple independent modules in the project, I had to do below setting in addition to [@activedecay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35052077/2685234):
Under `Project Settings`, click on `Modules`. Select specific module. Select appropriate `Language Level`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Okay, this helped me. I find it absurd IntelliJ defaulted to Java 1.5.

Comment: This Worked for me. Thnks Man

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem and none of the solutions I have found worked.

I was using Maven projects and so decided to try running a `maven install`.  It too said:

```
[ERROR]  thefile.java:[24,77] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] theFile.java:[91,62] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

So I added the properties to the Maven build `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

And refreshed the Maven project in IntelliJ.  It worked!

Comment: I ended up just running via mvn on the cli... Intelij is just not working for this.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem.

While I was accessing a static method of an interface through the name of the interface, I got the error saying

> static interface method invocations are not supported at this language level 5

As this is Java 1.8, I have checked some things:

1. I am using Intellij. So by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Project Structure dialog box opens, go to

   > Project -> Project language level

   set this to SDK default (8-Lambdas,type annotations etc).
2. In Project structure open

   > Modules -> Sources -> Language level

   set this to Project default (8-Lambdas,type annotations etc).
3. Apply-> OK.

Then the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell the solution in one image.

- **File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Properties tab -> Source Compatibility (Java 8)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I had that caused this error in a Gradle project was the `sourceCompatibility` setting in the build.gradle file.  This must also match the value you are expecting to need.  The default value that I have seen IntelliJ use when creating a new Gradle project is `1.5`.  If you are using lambdas, for instance, this will cause the build to fail.