# How to set language level for a Cordova plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051956/intellij-feature-not-supported-at-this-language-level-i-cant-compile) [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714584/what-is-project-language-level-in-intellij-idea) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703412/java-lambda-expressions-not-supported-at-this-language-level) about language lvl but none resolves my problem.

I am developing a Cordova plugin and I want to use annotation. The project was generated by `cordova build`, I have never used Android Studio before and I have this error message:

> @Override Annotations are not supported at this language level

I think I have something wrong in my project configuration, but I don't figure out what.

Here are the project structure tab often showed in the various questions I have seen

[image]

[image: Note I have not a version language switcher here]

Comment: It is not the answer as it is stated but I resolved my case with the help of a smart guy. I forgot to put `<platform name="android">
       <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
       ....
   </platform>` in the config.xml of my project. So the built project did not have a clue of what version to use.