# Try_catch block not supported android studio language level 8?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app in Android Studio :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    EditText noteTitleField, noteContentField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NoteAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String setValueInPrefs = sharedPreferences.getString("alreadyLaunched", null);
        try (setValueInPrefs.equals("0")) {
            Log.d("debugging", "App running for first time... launching setup");
            setupForFirstTime();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            noteContentField = findViewById(R.id.noteContentTextBox);
            noteTitleField = findViewById(R.id.noteTitleTextBox);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.welcomeMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting "Resource References are not supported at language level 8".

I checked some threads like this one [intellij feature (...) not supported at this language level. I can't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051956/intellij-feature-not-supported-at-this-language-level-i-cant-compile/35052077) to figure out where the error could be coming from but I checked both Project JDK versions and Android Studio JRE and they match on "java version 1.8"

Comment: Never catch nullpointerexceptions Check for null instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
try (setValueInPrefs.equals("0")) {
```

is not valid. In [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) code code in the parentheses must be an assignment statement (`VariableDeclaratorId = Expression`) and

> **The type of a variable declared in a resource specification must be a subtype of AutoCloseable, or a compile-time error occurs.**

[Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) relaxed the part with the assignment statement (now it can also be a variable or a field),  but still

> **The type of a variable declared or referred to as a resource in a resource specification must be a subtype of AutoCloseable, or a compile-time error occurs.**

You are using `setValueInPrefs.equals("0")` as expression, which results in a boolean value and `boolean` is not a subtype of AutoCloseable.

To fix it you should replace the `try` block with

```
    if (setValueInPrefs != null) {
        if (setValueInPrefs.equals("0")) {
            Log.d("debugging", "App running for first time... launching setup");
            setupForFirstTime();
        }
    } else {
        noteContentField = findViewById(R.id.noteContentTextBox);
        noteTitleField = findViewById(R.id.noteTitleTextBox);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.welcomeMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```